# Eclipse giving me Android API error I wasn't getting before

Tags: android

Eclipse is giving me an error on the following line:

```
decodedString= Base64.decode(imagestring, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

It says the decode method requires API 8 and my Manifest specifies the min API as 7.

```
Call requires API level 8 (current min is 7): android.util.Base64#decode
```

Here's my issue:

I've had this line of code in my app for months.  It has never given me this error before.  I opened this file in Eclipse, added 1 non-relevant line of code, and when I saved it gave me this error.

The only thing I can think is that yesterday I updated my SDK and Android plugin.

What can I do here?  Is my only option to increase my min API level to 8?  Why did it never give me this error before.  My project has specified 7 as the min API since its inception (well over a year).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing your API level to 8 looks sensible. Maybe the SDK/android plugin previously had a bug, since the documentation says it's API 8 and above.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore this error, please look at the picture below

[image]

Comment: ignoring it would mean risking crashes on none compatible devices. using @targetApi annotation seems more sensible

Comment: Yes this way has the risk on none compatible devices